# Как поместить каждый файл в отдельный архив 7zip в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

вот пример кода в `cmd` (`bat`):

```
set _in=C:\Users\cat\Desktop\3
set _out=C:\Users\cat\Desktop\3
set _arcpath=C:\Program Files\7-Zip
for %%i in (%_in%\*.*) do "%_arcpath%\7z" a "%_out%\%%~ni%%~xi-(%date%).7z" "%%i"
pause
```

Нужно переделать этот код под Python 3.

Такой код добавляет все файлы в один архив:
`subprocess.call([r'"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -mx0 a ' + dt+'.7z'])` ,

а нужно каждый файл в отдельный архив.

Comment: Как пробовали реализовать, что не получилось?

Comment: например так: 

for file in listdir('.'):
 subprocess.call(r'"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -mx0 a ' +(file) +'.7z')

но в каждом архиве всеравно все файлы, а не один

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почти буквальный перевод исходного bat-скрипта:

```
import os
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime as dt

_in = r'C:\Users\cat\Desktop\3'
_out = r'C:\Users\cat\Desktop\3'
archiver = r'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'

for filename in os.listdir(_in):
    # Если исходная директория совпадает с выходной, и бэкап уже делался, лучше пропускать файлы архивов:
    if not filename.endswith('.7z'):  
         timestr = dt.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')
         subprocess.call(r'"{ar}" a "{pth}\{fn}_{dt}.7z" "{fn}"'.format(ar=archiver, pth=_out, fn=filename, dt=timestr))

input('Press Enter to continue...')  # вместо pause
```

Получилось немного топорно, но работать по идее должно.

Comment: О! Спасибо! попробую сейчас :)

Работает!!! Спасибо Огромное!

Comment: 1- можно использовать `dt=date.today()`, чтобы ближе к `%date%` формат был и чтобы строковое представление порядок сортировки даты сохраняло бы: `'%Y-%m-%d'`. 2- Для одноразового скрипта это не важно, но легко сделать его кросс-платформенным: `src_dir, dest_dir = sys.argv[1:]`, `os.path.join()`  вместо `"{}\{}"`, `path7z = '7z' и передать список в `subprocess.call()` (кстати, можно предупреждение печатать, если неудачно завершился для файла). Также можно убрать `input()` в конце  и посоветовать запускать с консоли или создать ярлык с `cmd /k`